# trim whitespaces in oracle where condition

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm facing the following issues when i tried to retrieve the data from oracle database by trimming the whitespace. I'm using oracle 12G version.

Let's say the name column has some whitespaces like 'Test       '.

Table name - PGM_DETAIL

```
ID     NAME 
1      Test
```

When I'm trying to fetch the data using following query. It's not fetching it.

```
SELECT * FROM PGM_DETAIL WHERE TRIM(NAME) = TRIM('Test');
```

Could you anyone please suggest me what the problem in my sql statement.

Thanks in advance...,

Comment: `WHERE` keyword missing.

Comment: TRIM does only trim <space> characters. I'd look for REGEXP something instead.

Comment: In your example, you show the column value in mixed case:  'Test '.  In your query, you are checking for it in all UPPERCASE:  WHERE TRIM(NAME) = TRIM('TEST');   'Test' does not equal 'TEST'.

Comment: You commented that none of suggested answers help. From my point of view, they should. If they don't, then there's something else you didn't say. Please, post a **test case** (CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO several sample rows) which illustrate the problem.

Comment: @Littlefoot It's not working in one of Oracle 11.0.2 version. Do i need to give any privilege ?

Comment: There's nothing I'd like to add to my previous comment at the moment, DIVA.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle comparisons are case-sensitive by default.

So try:

```
WHERE UPPER(TRIM(NAME)) = TRIM('TEST');
```

Comment: Yeah. You are right. I wrongly put the data in upper case. Check my updated question.

Comment: _"Check my updated question"_  Thus suggesting that even with that consideration, your query is still not producing the results you want.  Please read and heed https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

try

```
SELECT * FROM PGM_DETAIL WHERE TRIM(NAME) = TRIM('Test');
```